# How to default date time format to normal datetime in CakePHP 3.x?

Tags: php, datetime, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using CakePHP-3.2 and when ever I try to retrieve date related data from DB tables e.g. date_of_birth which is saved in `DATETIME` format in MySQL, CakePHP keeps returning it in `Cake\I18n\FrozenTime Object`. Which according to CakePHP's documentation is immutable data.

Is there any settings in `bootstrap.php` or `app.php` which I can set to tell CakePHP to return date data in normal date time format?

Comment: And your problem with the object is...? You're trying to resolve a non problem. The object can return whatever format you want via the format() method.

Comment: Hi @burzum I want to use this date to populate an input box in a grid, and I don't know how to format this object.

Comment: you can add this line in boostrap.php with your required format  `Cake\I18n\FrozenDate::setToStringFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');`

Comment: it doesn't make any difference tarikul